# laravel check if collection contains model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a many to many relation:

```
users (id)

user_game (user_id, game_id)

games (id, title)
```

I want to check if a game is associated to a specific user:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$game = Game::where('title', 'pacman');

$gameUsers = $game->users()
$gameHasUser =  >>> $gameUsers contains $user <<< // How can I do this?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For many-to-many you can use [`contains()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-contains) method:

```
$game = Game::where('title', 'pacman')->first();
if ($game->users->contains($userId)) {
    // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `->user()` , so your code would become:

```
$gameHasUser =  $gameUsers->find(1)->user()
```

`find(1)` is just an example for illustration. You can also check [Eloquent Loading Relationships Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Answer (score 0):

You can use where clause to check game existence in the user's game list:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$gameHasUser = $user->games()->where('title', 'pacman')->isNotEmpty();
```